# Algum tipo de alerta com Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-notification

Desenvolvi um aplicativo onde os usuários acessam e podem salvar algumas coisas (nome, endereço etc). Essas configurações ficam disponíveis para um usuário administrador visualizar e modificar se for o caso. Estou usando o firebase como persistência.

O que gostaria de saber se é possível, que quando algum usuário inserir um novo registro, o Firebase verificar a mudança surgir algum aviso ou som para que o administrador saiba que tem algo novo para ele verificar.

Answer (score 1):

Vai depender muito da forma como você pensou sua arquitetura, mas se for uma situação onde o ADM está sempre com o app/página aberto, mantenha um ChildEventListener acoplado na sua referência do banco, e no eventos do listener você trabalha com os novos dados que forem vindo. Vou colocar o trecho de código do sample do Google abaixo para entendimento, é o mesmo que sempre uso nos meus apps. Com relação a notificação de itens novos, use a propria NotificationCompat para notificar o usuário no evento onChildAdded:

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        //Evento que vai mostrar toda child que for adicionada na Reference.
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        //Evento que vai mostrar toda child que foi modificada.
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Evento que vai mostrar toda child que for removida da Reference.
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        //Evento que vai mostrar toda child que for reordenada na Reference. Particularmente nunca utilizei este evento.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Evento que vai mostrar todo erro que acontecer no banco de dados.
    }
};
ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```